# content-transfer-encoding standards for text/plain attachments

Tags: email, mime-types, content-type, mime

If I create multipart/mixed MIME message do I need to use `Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64` for any `Content-Type: text/plain` attachment? Or any `text/plain` can be set as `Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable` as well and going be delivered as a proper attachment?